# Source from string? Is there any way in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "$VARIABLE"
```

Is to retrieve values from a remote location using curl.

```
http://example.com/file.cnfg
```

Comment: Apparently you are trying to say that `VARIABLE="curl 'http://example.com/file.cnfg'"` and this is what you want to evaluate. As an aside (and as implied in rici's answer) you should not use upper case for your private variables; uppercase is reserved for system variables.

Comment: A complete answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522007/61742 . 

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Executing downloads blindly is definitely not something you want to do casually.

You can execute the contents of a variable using `eval`, as in:

```
eval "$variable"
```

That's not something you want to do without thinking through the security implications either.

Comment: I am beginner in bash, so I am a bit blindly. But if the request is to my own server, you also need to consider security issues?

Comment: @RobinPlotnik: Security is not just about malicious attacks. Suppose your server returns an error instead of the data you expect, and your code executes the error as though it were a shell script. How sure are you that the random content of the error does not contain something which could do damage? HTML contains lots of >, for example. How possible is it that the next word happens to name a file?

Answer (score 22):

You don't need or want a variable. The common way to do this is

```
curl http://example.com/file.cnfg | sh
```

If you really genuinely need to execute the code in the current shell,

```
source <(curl http://example.com/file.cnfg)
```

does that.

Caveats about security implications cannot be overstated. You need to understand what could go wrong if the server is malicious, hijacked, misconfigured, down, or just in a really grumpy mood.

You should be asking yourself  "can I avoid using a variable" (and also, "can I avoid spawning an external process") and if the answer is yes, that's usually what you should do.